# In Python3 what is the syntax to specify a specific sub object?

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, object

I am accessing a web JSON, using request and json. I can call primary objects from the array, but I can't figure out the syntax to call a sub object or object inside of an object. Here is a snippet of the JSON I'm working with:

```
[
  {
     "round":1,
     "roster_id":null,
     "player_id":"4034",
     "picked_by":"343691457850322944",
     "pick_no":1,
     "metadata": 

    {
       "years_exp":"3",
       "team":"CAR",
       "status":"Active",
       "sport":"nfl",
       "position":"RB",
       "player_id":"4034",
       "number":"22",
       "news_updated":"1577664318550",
       "last_name":"McCaffrey",
       "injury_status":"",
       "first_name":"Christian"},

     "is_keeper":null,
     "draft_slot":1,
     "draft_id":"549087829381697536"},
```

And here is my full code. I have left a snippet of the problem section at the bottom. My code works fine, but it just keeps giving me ALL of the metadata. I am trying to only pull metadata/first_name/last_name/position. (I want only those items out of the metadata).

```
import requests
import json

def job():

    print('What is Sleeper App user name?')
    user_name = (input())

    user_data = requests.get("https://api.sleeper.app/v1/user/"+user_name).json()

    user = (user_data['user_id'])

    print("User ID:"+user+"\n")

    draft_data = requests.get("https://api.sleeper.app/v1/user/"+user+"/drafts/nfl/2020").json()

    draft_lists = []

    for item in draft_data:
        draft_details = {'draft_id':None}
        draft_details = item['draft_id']
        draft_lists.append(draft_details)
    print(user_name+"Draft Id's"+"\n")
    print(draft_lists)
    print("\n")
    print("Type the Draft ID that you would like to inspect")
    draftinput = (input())

    draftpickdata = requests.get("https://api.sleeper.app/v1/draft/"+draftinput+"/picks").json()

    draft_picks = []

    for item in draftpickdata:
        pick_details = {'pick_no':None}, {'metadata':{'position'}}
        pick_details = item['pick_no'] 
        pick_details = item['metadata']
        draft_picks.append(pick_details)

    print("Draft "+draftinput+" Picks \n" + str(draft_picks))

while True:
    try:
        job()
    except:
        print("Invalid User Name"+"\n")
        pass
```

You can run my code here if you want: https://repl.it/@weston6949/DraftPicksWork

Problem Section Snippet:

```
draftinput = (input())
draftpickdata = requests.get("https://api.sleeper.app/v1/draft/"+draftinput+"/picks").json()
draft_picks = []
for item in draftpickdata:
    pick_details = {'pick_no':None}, {'metadata':{'position'}}
    pick_details = item['pick_no'] 
    pick_details = item['metadata']
    draft_picks.append(pick_details)
print("Draft "+draftinput+" Picks \n" + str(draft_picks))
```

Comment: You need to make a [mre]. This is too much code for what seems like a simple problem. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: In your snippet at the bottom you are assigning a value to the `pick_details` variable 3 times subsequently. I'm not certain what exactly you're trying to achieve but whenever you assign a new value, the previous value is lost. So your first 2 assignments are useless.

Comment: And to answer you question, to access the `"first_name"` element, you would simply use `item['metadata']['first_name']` and so on. I suggest you read up on python dictionaries as those are the objects you're referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks here is the what worked:

```py
draftpickdata = requests.get("https://api.sleeper.app/v1/draft/" + draftinput + "/picks").json()

draft_picks = []

for item in draftpickdata:
    pick_details = item['pick_no'], item['metadata']['first_name'], item['metadata']['last_name'], item['metadata']['position'] 
    draft_picks.append(pick_details)

print("Draft "+draftinput+" Picks \n" + str(draft_picks))
```